# How to specify datetime format in C# Deedle when reading and writing CSV?

Tags: c#, csv, datetime, datetime-format, deedle

Assuming I have the following `data.csv` file.

```
Timestamp,DoubleCol,BooleanCol,StringCol
04/15/2020 06:45:02.085-07:00,1.52,True,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:03.057-07:00,2.32,False,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:04.058-07:00,4.55,True,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:05.057-07:00,1.52,False,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:06.057-07:00,2.32,True,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:07.057-07:00,4.55,False,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:08.057-07:00,1.52,True,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:09.058-07:00,2.32,False,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:10.057-07:00,4.55,True,Some String
04/15/2020 06:45:11.057-07:00,1.02,False,Some String
```

I need to read this CSV into a Frame, do some filtering on the Timestamp column and then write a CSV but with the Timestamp column as an ISO 8601 string.

If I simply do this, the first column is of type String, not DateTimeOffset.

```cs
filePath = "data.csv";
timestampFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fffK"; // This is sent along with the CSV file.
var frame = Frame.ReadCsv(filePath);
```

Also, if I try this:

```cs
var tsFrame = frame.IndexRows<DateTime>("Timestamp");
```

I get

```
FormatException: String '04/15/2020 06:45:02.085-07:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

So how can I specify the DateTime format to use when parsing the first column?

And then, how can I specify use ISO 8601 when writing the CSV out?

**NOTE**

This is a simplified scenario. In reality, I don't know the schema in advance. Except that the first column is the timestamp (which I also receive the format for). The rest of the columns can be anything. So I need a solution that doesn't rely on a compile-time schema.

Comment: Use zzz instead of K : "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffzzz";

Comment: I don't have control over the format. I just receive it. But yeah, I can always replace the `K` with `zzz`.

Comment: Can you read data after making change?  When writing use tsFrame.ToStroing(""MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fffzzz"")

Answer (score 4):

First, your timestamp format is not correct. You have a format `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fffK"` with `:` before the `fffK`, but your sample data have `.` before milliseconds i.e. `04/15/2020 06:45:10.057-07:00`.

Now, there is no easy way of specifying the exact date time parse format when calling `ReadCsv`, but you can use the `Select` operation and `ReplaceColumn` to read the data as `string` and then parse the dates explicitly:

```
df.ReplaceColumn("Timestamp",
  df.GetColumn<string>("Timestamp").Select(kvp => 
    DateTime.ParseExact(kvp.Value, timestampFormat, 
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)));
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great. I've added `.ToUniversalTime()` to have them in UTC. Now, `ReplaceColumn`seems to delete the original and append the new one, so now Timestamp is at the end. Anyway to put it back as the first column?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if there is an easy way to just switch the order. It does not matter for any actual runtime operations, but I guess it's nice to have the column first for previews. You might be able to sort the columns using `SortColumnsByKey`, but that will do alphabetic sort. Otherwise, you might need to create a new frame by adding all the columns one by one (which would actually be okay and should be efficient enough).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Deedle, but you could try using my library [`Sylvan.Data.Csv`](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan/blob/master/docs/Sylvan.Data.Csv.md), (available as a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sylvan.Data.Csv/)) which allows reading CSV data with a schema. Looking at the Deedle API: `Frame` also has a `ReadReader` method that allows providing an `IDataReader`, so my library should integrate easily.

```
using var tr = File.OpenText("data.csv");

var schema = new TypedCsvSchema();
schema.Add(0, typeof(DateTime));
schema.Add(1, typeof(double));
schema.Add(2, typeof(bool));
schema.Add(3, typeof(string));

var options = new CsvDataReaderOptions { Schema = schema };
DbDataReader dr = CsvDataReader.Create(tr, options);


var frame = Frame.ReadReader(dr);
```